# What sort of weapons do the Eminians employ?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, weapon

In "A Taste of Armageddon," Kirk and company find that the Eminians are in a sort of "computer" war with the Vendikans. In the episode, Eminian weapons are displayed and used, but, unlike a Federation phaser, do not produce a visual stream of energy when fired.

The energy, or whatever it uses, is invisible to the human eye, and quite likely also the Eminian eye.

What sort of weapon is it? If nothing in canon speaks to this, non-canon sources are acceptable.

[image: Captain Kirk brandishing two of the Eminian weapons]

*Captain Kirk brandishing two of the weapons while on Eminiar VII*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Their weapons (described in the script as "[sonic disruptors](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sonic_disruptor)") appear to employ a highly focused 'beam' of sound.

> Terrified, the remaining people in the queue turned and ran. Spock
> joined the Captain, eyeing the gun he had just confiscated with open
> curiosity, his eyebrows up. “A fascinating weapon. Is it solely sonic,
> I wonder? If so, how do they keep it in a tight beam?”
>
> <sub><sup>James Blish - Star Trek 2: A Taste of Armageddon - Official Novelisation</sup></sub>

and

> **DEPAUL:** *Screens firm, sir. Extremely powerful sonic vibrations. Decibels eighteen to the twelfth power. If those screens weren't up,
> we'd be totally disrupted by now.*
>
> <sub><sup>[TOS: A Taste of Armageddon](http://www.chakoteya.net/StarTrek/23.htm)</sup></sub>